# Is the sentence correct or shortened?

Tags: sentence-meaning, ellipsis

Let's look at the sentence.

> He doesn't want to see me win.

Is it shortened? Is it correct grammatically? I think the sentence should be as follows.

> He doesn't want to see me to win.

or

> He doesn't want to see that I win.

Please make me know it with explanation.

Answer (score 5):

"He doesn't want to see me win" is a perfectly grammatical sentence. The verbs of perception such as "see", "hear" and "listen" can take a bare-infintival clause as a complement.

*"He doesn't want to see me to win" is not grammatical, at least in this context. It could be grammatical if "to win" was a purpose adjunct: cf. "He doesn't want to see me in order to win."

"He doesn't want to see that I win" is grammatical, but doesn't make much sense. "See" in this case is  synonymous to "realize".